# PHP new IMAP email notification + getting its contents (cron)

Tags: php, sql, email, cron

I need a PHP script that will check if I have new email and then it will throw it in my My SQL table with its date, from email and its content. I can use CRON for it. But I don't know how to get the emails. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading emails can be done using PHP's IMAP functions. More info at PHP.net:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Comment: Thanks much. Hope I can make the scripr I need working!